# How do you interface an event dispatcher?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-components

I'm attempting to interface an event dispatcher and having a hell of a time coming up with a solution. So far i have the following simple interface:

```
interface EventDispatcherInterface
{
    public function fire($name, $data);
}
```

Now i'm trying to implement it using symfony's `EventDispatcher`. The problem is that symfony's `dispatch` method expects the second argument to implement its `Event` abstract class. Ok..so now i have to come up with a wrapper class?

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;

class SymfonyEvent extends Event
{
    private $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->data;
    }
}
```

Here's the first pass at an implementation

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher as SymfonyEventDispatcher;

class SymfonyDispatcher implements EventDispatcherInterface
{
    protected $dispatcher;

    public function __construct(SymfonyEventDispatcher $dispatcher = null)
    {
        $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher ? : new SymfonyEventDispatcher;
    }

    public function fire($name, $data)
    {
        $event = new SymfonyEvent($data);

        $this->dispatcher->dispatch($name, $event);
    }
}
```

How do i go about writing agnostic event listeners?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about why you need this?  Seems like the SymfonyDispatcher would do the trick.  If you really want a fire method then you could just extend the symfony dispatcher class and then tweak the config files to use your own dispatcher.  But why?

Comment: i'm attempting to write a framework agnostic package. It's proved a challenge!

Comment: Keep in mind that Symfony EventDispatcher is a component and is independent of the Symfony framework.  Try convincing yourself that having your package require the use of a particular component still meets the agnostic requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
class SymfonyEventDispatcher implements EventDispatcher
{

    private $eventDispatcher;

    public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher)
    {
        $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
    }

    public function dispatch(Event $event)
    {
        $listeners = $this->eventDispatcher->getListeners($event->getName());

        foreach ($listeners as $listener) {
            call_user_func($listener, $event);
        }
    }
}
```

From Matthais Noback's great blog on exactly your problem:
http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2014/08/symfony2-decoupling-your-event-system/